# Lazyload images without hurting SEO

Tags: javascript, css, seo, lazy-loading

We have a product details page on our website and it has a preview of a large image of the product. The problem is because of it being too large and hi-res, it takes time to load and render on our page. Now I've read about something called image upscaling or from what I've understood it works a bit more like lazyloading the images. So the concept is they generate a very small, in terms of file size and image dimension, version of the large image and set it as the initial preview of the image. Then size it up to same as the large image's original dimension. So it is stretched and they blur it out. They wait for the larger image to load then replace the smaller one with it once it is done loading. I've seen this in multiple blogs and news website and it seems like a very good solution. But my concern is, does this affect our page's SEO? If so, is there a way to implement this kind of behavior without hurting our page's SEO?

Comment: It depends on how the plugin works but with lazy loading plugin they utilize `data-src` so the original `<img>` tag is unaffected thus not effecting SEO.

Comment: But this would mean the original src is the smaller image. Since this will be the one being served initially while waiting for the larger one. If the smaller image version would be initially assigned to the <img> tag then it will be the one being indexed instead of the actual hi res one. Am I right?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO, not programming. SEO questions may be asked on [Webmasters.SE](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you have a problem with optimizing your images. To solve this, I recommend that you apply the following techniques:

- **Add the *srcset* attribute to the img element**. The **[srcset](https://html.com/attributes/img-srcset/)** attribute extends the functionality of the img element. If the browser does not support the srcset attribute, by default the image file is imported using the src attribute. If the browser supports the srcset attribute, you can specify a list of image sources and conditions (comma-separated) before the request is received. As a result, only those images that match the parameters of the device are downloaded and displayed.
- ***Art direction* in the responsive images with the element *picture***. If you want the images to vary depending on the characteristics of the device (art direction effect), use the element **[picture](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_picture.asp)**. The picture element specifies a declarative solution to provide multiple versions of the same image, depending on the various characteristics of the device: size, resolution, destination, and so on.

```html
<picture>
  <source media="(min-width: 800px)" srcset="head.jpg, head-2x.jpg 2x">
  <source media="(min-width: 450px)" srcset="head-small.jpg, head-small-2x.jpg 2x">
  <img src="head-fb.jpg" srcset="head-fb-2x.jpg 2x" alt="a head carved out of wood">
</picture>
```

In the above example, if the width of the browser is not less than 800 pixels, the *head.jpg* or *head-2x.jpg* format will be used (depending on the screen resolution of the device).If the width of the browser is from 450 to 800 pixels, the formats *head-small.jpg* or *head-small-2x.jpg* (also depending on the screen resolution of the device) are applied. If we are talking about a screen width of less than 450 pixels and a device with downward compatibility, the picture element will not be supported. In this case, the browser uses the img element to display the image on the screen (it must be enabled).

- **Images with relative dimensions**. If the final image size is unknown, it is difficult to select the pixel density descriptor for image sources. This, in particular, refers to images that are stretched proportionally to the width of the browser and change their size depending on it. In this case does not indicate the fixed image size and pixel density. Instead, you can determine the size of the image being processed by adding a handle to width. This will allow the browser to automatically calculate the optimal pixel density and select the correct image to load.

```html
<img src="lighthouse-200.jpg" sizes="50vw"
     srcset="lighthouse-100.jpg 100w, lighthouse-200.jpg 200w,
             lighthouse-400.jpg 400w, lighthouse-800.jpg 800w,
             lighthouse-1000.jpg 1000w, lighthouse-1400.jpg 1400w,
             lighthouse-1800.jpg 1800w" alt="a lighthouse">
```

This example shows an image that takes half the width of the viewport (sizes = "50vw" when applying the **[viewport](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp)**) and depends on the width of the browser and its ratio of logical and physical pixels. As a result, the browser can select an image that will be displayed correctly in a window of any size.

Please note that images of the **JPG-JPEG** format have approximately 50% less volume than **PNG**. Therefore, they are easier and faster to load. To change the image format and resize images, you can use this tool [Photo Editor Online](https://pixlr.com/editor/). To compress images, you can use this tool - **[JPEG and PNG compressors](https://imageoptim.com/online)**.

The best solution is the use of **[Accelerated Mobile Pages AMP](https://ampbyexample.com/)**. Please note that in their implementation of the **[image](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-img/)** element is also used the srcset attribute.

**[Original source](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/responsive/images)** ++ **[Use Cases and Requirements for Standardizing Responsive Images](http://usecases.responsiveimages.org/)** ++ **[Responsive images of MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images)**.

You can use for preloading images of the current web page with meta **preload**, eg: `<link rel="preload" href="//examples.com/images/img1.jpg" as="image">` 
Read more **[Preload of W3C](https://w3c.github.io/preload/)** ++ **[Preloading content with rel="preload" of Moz](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content)**.

Comment: So your solution is to serve different image sizes for different browser breakpoints? This would be beneficial for mobile but would still mean we'll serve a larger image for larger screens and would still take time to load. My original concern is how to lazyload this large images without impacting SEO

Answer (score 0):

For SEO I'm going to assume you want to go by googles standards for my answer.

lazy loading will help your bandwidth, not your SEO google will judge your website by full page load time.

I recommend you compress your images and that will be all the difference.

if you have any pictures you can load 20 pics and the have a button saying load more, then lazy load from there.
this would be a big SEO boost as your now loading half your website.

Comment: Best is to serve an url where u provide the image in a lower solution. Maybe you should generate it on demand and save it. Google will also crawl and index images in the data-src field: Google is not stupid ;-) Make them all progressive (if jpegs) . Lazy load helps you to prevent to download images which are not in the screen right now, and load them when they are needed A high load time is okay for google, if your users accept high load times, btw. Your website can be as fast as hell, if the users don't bounce, it's okay. Better with a good performance, that's true. But first think about user

Comment: Unfortunately I can't lazy load the image with a button or on scroll of page because the image I want to lazyload is the product preview which should be the one shown to the user immediately.

I didn't know google indexes data-src. Do you have any source link to prove this?

Comment: well, to be honest, its a debated topic if google can read data-src, I believe that it does but let's assume it cant.
If google cant read data-src then you will lose some good SEO from the pictures alt"" attribute.

Comment: If you add your website name i can give you a better answer on what i think will work best for you.

Comment: Compressing the images results in a blurry one, and will hurt the brand / shop. I am not sure how does some of the shops do it, they have a page loaded with banners and images and still rank 1 on Google search